# How can I configure AWS SNS subscription in a Django Web server deployed on Beanstalk?

Tags: django, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sns

I plan to set the django web server subscribing to aws sns. So each time when there is a notification form sns, the django server can get the notification via http request.

In this case, what should I do to make the server be able do handle the imcoming http request from sns all the time?

I've already written a function to handle the POST json data. But how can I let the server process the POST request with that function? I didn't find any url pattern for this POST from SNS and unable to define the url pattern in urls.py.

Comment: Doesn't Amazon's SNS send a `POST` request each time there is a notification? Parse the body and do whatever logic you need.

Comment: I've already written a function to handle the POST json data. But how can I let the server process the POST request with that function? I didn't find any url pattern for this POST from SNS and unable to define the url pattern in urls.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure all SNS functionality either using the AWS Console, a SDK or an command line interface. You don't directly configure it within your application.

- For getting started you should head over to the AWS console and choose the SNS service.
- Create a topic
- Select the topic
- Click create subscription, choose protocol HTTP and enter your endpoint, meaning the URL to your Django Webserver and service.
- Confirm the subscription using the headers from the request captured by your application.

So basically you configure the URL which SNS should use within the AWS console and not within your application. You can name the URL whatever you want as long it's a valid URL. There is a [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html) detailing all steps including the confirmation of the subscription.